# A tool to detect unnecessary recursive calls in a program?

Tags: language-agnostic, recursion

A very common beginner mistake when writing recursive functions is to accidentally fire off completely redundant recursive calls from the same function.  For example, consider this recursive function that finds the maximum value in a binary tree (not a binary search tree):

```
int BinaryTreeMax(Tree* root) {
    if (root == null) return INT_MIN;

    int maxValue = root->value;
    if (maxValue < BinaryTreeMax(root->left))
        maxValue = BinaryTreeMax(root->left);   // (1)
    if (maxValue < BinaryTreeMax(root->right))
        maxValue = BinaryTreeMax(root->right);  // (2)

    return maxValue;
}
```

Notice that this program potentially makes two completely redundant recursive calls to `BinaryTreeMax` in lines (1) and (2).  We could rewrite this code so that there's no need for these extra calls by simply caching the value from before:

```
int BinaryTreeMax(Tree* root) {
    if (root == null) return INT_MIN;

    int maxValue = root->value;
    int leftValue = BinaryTreeMax(root->left);
    int rightValue = BinaryTreeMax(root->right);

    if (maxValue < leftValue)
        maxValue = leftValue;
    if (maxValue < rightValue)
        maxValue = rightValue;

    return maxValue;
}
```

Now, we always make exactly two recursive calls.

My question is whether there is a tool that does either a static or dynamic analysis of a program (in whatever language you'd like; I'm not too picky!) that can detect whether a program is making completely unnecessary recursive calls.  By "completely unnecessary" I mean that

1. The recursive call has been made before,
2. by the same invocation of the recursive function (or one of its descendants), and
3. the call itself has no observable side-effects.

This is something that can usually be determined by hand, but I think it would be great if there were some tool that could flag things like this automatically as a way of helping students gain feedback about how to avoid making simple but expensive mistakes in their programs that could contribute to huge inefficiencies.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your definition of 'completely unnecessary' is insufficient. It is possible that some code between the two function calls affects the result of the second function call.

Second, this has nothing to do with recursion, the same question can apply to any function call. If it has been called before with the exact same parameters, has no side-effects, and no code between the two calls changed any data the function accesses.

Now, I'm pretty sure a perfect solution is impossible, as it would solve [The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), but that doesn't mean there isn't a way to detect enough of these cases and optimize away some of them.

Some compilers know how to do that (GCC has a specific flag that warns you when it does so). Here's a 2003 article I found about the issue: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jsstylos/15745/final.pdf .

I couldn't find a tool for this, though, but that's probably something Eric Lipert knows, if he happens to bump into your question.

Comment: I completely agree that this is impossible in general.  While I agree that there's a more general question here that considers, more generally, any function call, I'm specifically interested in recursive calls because the cost of duplicating recursive work can be huge (this is why, for example, memoization and DP are so effective at decreasing runtimes!)

Comment: I don't think it's a more general question, I think it's exactly the same question. I can't imagine how a solution for recursive calls is not going to work for any other function calls.

Comment: With recursion, you can localize your search to the function calls made by one function and its descendants.  In the more general case, you may have to do some sort of interprocedural analysis to locate redundancies.  I would expect that the recursive version could be optimized to take advantage of this and thus be a bit easier to implement.

Comment: Re: "Second, this has nothing to do with recursion, the same question can apply to any function call": That's technically true, but without recursion such redundant calls wouldn't affect the algorithmic complexity (except by a constant factor), whereas in the OP's example, the redundant calls change the complexity from linear time to quadratic time if the tree is guaranteed to be well-balanced, and from linear time to worst-case exponential time (!) if it's not.

Comment: We're discussing a hypothetical solution here, let's discuss this matter when there's a real solution at hand. Right now my best solution is "don't handle it at all", and it applies equally well to all function calls :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers (such as GCC) do have ways to mark determinate functions explicitly (to be more precise,  `__attribute__((const))` (see [GCC function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) applies some restrictions onto the function body to make its result depend only from its argument and get no depency from shared state of program or other non-deterministic functions). Then they eliminate duplicate calls to costy functions. Some other high-level language implementations (may be Haskell) does this tests automatically.

Really, I don't know tools for such analysis (but if i find it i will be happy). And if there is one that correcly detects unnecessary recursion or, in general way, function evaluation (in language-agnostic environment) it would be a kind of determinacy prover.

BTW, it's not so difficult to write such program when you already have access to semantic tree of the code :)

Comment: In Haskell it's a lot easier, you make sure all your side-effects are well defined.

Comment: @IraBaxter i'm not sure if I named this right. But how can we call a representation of program where nodes are functions and edges designate data flow? It might be an oriented graph rather than tree.
EDIT: Some googling told that "semantic tree" in linguistics shows the derivation of meaning. So it's definitely wrong term. But if you know the right and exact one, could you tell it, please?

Comment: @AndrewD. "Nodes are functions and edges designate data flow"? Well that would be a data flow graph but you don't want the functions to be opaque. Maybe you meant a data flow graph for the function itself in which the nodes are operators. But to determine if a function has side effects, you need an AST, local flow analysis, and a call graph; f has a side effect if it has a side effect in its body or it calls another function which has a side effect. Determing that f has useless recursion is a lot harder; worse, it may have side effects that cancel.